# Can't get a typo3 template to work

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

So I only have a few days to make a typo3 site, and since I am not familiar with it, I decided I would install a template and just change it around a bit.
Whenever I try to import the .t3d file as the instructions in the .txt of the template I get two errors: When I upload it, I get

> "file does not contain data for 'files_fal'"

I have been unable to find out what this means or I get a message saying:

> The reference UID for the file (sys_file_reference) has to be numeric. UID given: "C:/xampp/htdocs/site/typo3temp/var/transient/xxxxx.tmp

xxx being the name of the .tmp file that gets created every time I try to do this. 
How do I fix this? It's most likely something on my side, but I have not been able to find out what.

Edit: @KevinAppelt My current typo3 version is 8.7.4- should be the newest. The template i downloaded from a site i realised is from 2014. It does seem like incompatibility now that i think about it. Kind of silly that i did not notice, but thank you for pointing it out. Hopefully i will figure out the rest on my own.

Comment: Please provide further information. Which version of TYPO3 do you use? Is the template you try to install compatible with this version? Where do you get the template from? At the moment it looks like an incompatibility to me.

Answer (score 0):

Transfering a complete configuration by t3d-files is not really state of the art. So I assume you have an old tutorial with a t3d file and a new version of TYPO3 which does not match well. (You should give more information about versions and maybe sources of your information).

If you want an easy installation with ready to fill configuration you might install TYPO3 and install one of the available "preconfigured distribution".
While installing this option will be available as last step.

You also can install a distribution afterwards (but better before you insert any pages or content).
Just go to the Extension-Manager and select "get preconfigured Distributions" in the drop down.

Comment: Yes i realise now that i was using an old template with an old tutorial. I will see what i can do, but for some reason the "get preconfigured distributions" is not working. I dont know, theres definitely some problems with the typo3 intallation itself as I've had many other (minor) issues. Thank you for the answer though. Sadly, most of the documentation i can find is either outdated or in german :/